# compiler doesn't complain about function not returning value

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, compiler-errors, return

I have the following function:

```
bool Server::ServerInit()
{
//  bool listenResult = socket.Listen( (const uint8 *)_LOCAL_HOST, m_iPort );
//  if( true == listenResult )
//      cout << "Server passive socket listening\n";
//  else
//      cout << "Server passive socket not listening\n";
//      
//  return listenResult;
} // ServerInit()
```

this compiles perfectly fine, but shouldn't the compiler be complaining about the absence of a return statement?

EDIT 0: GNU g++ compiler

Comment: What compiler are you using? The Visual C++ compiler I have complains about your code snippet rather loudly with a C4716.

Comment: @TheFuzz: Mine complains rather loudly too as it should!

Comment: I made an edit. I'm using the gnu g++ compiler

Comment: @TheFuzz: Indeed g++ doesn't complain by default. Surprising...

Comment: Why is that not set as a default setting for g++?

Comment: @TheFuzz : I dont know. Which version of `g++` are you using?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try compiling with `-Wall` option (gcc)[ `-Wreturn-type` to be more precise]. You'll a get a warning something like "Control reaches end of a non-void function" or something like "no return statement in function returning non-void"

Example:

```
C:\Users\SUPER USER\Desktop>type no_return.cpp
#include <iostream>
int func(){}

int main()
{
   int z = func();
   std::cout<< z; //Undefined Behaviour
}
C:\Users\SUPER USER\Desktop>g++ -Wall no_return.cpp
no_return.cpp: In function 'int func()':
no_return.cpp:2:12: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void

C:\Users\SUPER USER\Desktop>
```

Using the returned value of a non-void function (having no return statement) is Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: -Wall is listed as one of the options my compiler is currently using. It still doesn't complain.

Comment: You need "-Wall", not "-wall"; the command line options are case sensitive. Note that "-w" is "inhibit all warning messages".

Comment: @TheFuzz I get the following when I use -Wall: "test.cpp: In member function 'bool Server::ServerInit()':
test.cpp:14: warning: control reaches end of non-void function"

Answer (score 1):

Here's the reason as to why you do not get error/warning as it is something which is known as Undefined Behavior (UB)

> $6.6.3/2 - "Flowing off the end of a
>   function is equivalent to a return
>   with no value; **this results in
>   undefined behavior in a
>   value-returning function.**"

Unfortunately, a clean compilation with/without warning apart from any other imaginable behavior is all part of UB.

As @Prasoon mentioned, 'main' function is an exception to this rule.

Comment: Also add that `main()` is an exception to this rule. `:)`