# Segmentation fault adding two large numbers represented as strings

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, biginteger

Here is the code snippet or rather a function which takes two strings as inputs which are basically large integers and prints the sum of them. I am getting the sum printed correctly, but a segmentation fault comes up at the end and I am unable to figure out its source.

```
string sum(string x, string y) {
    bool carry = false;
    int yLen = y.length(), xLen = x.length();
    vector<char> s;
    for(int i = xLen - 1, j = yLen - 1; i >= 0, j >= 0; i--, j--) {
        int a = x[i] - '0', b = y[j] - '0';
        int c = (carry?(a+b+1):(a+b));
        if(c/10)        carry = true, c %= 10;
        else            carry = false;
        s.push_back(c + '0');
    }
    for(int i = xLen - yLen - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        int a = x[i] - '0';
        int c = (carry?(a+1):(a));
        if(c/10)        carry = true, c %= 10;
        else            carry = false;
        s.push_back(c + '0');
    }
    reverse(s.begin(), s.end());
    for(vector<char>::iterator i = s.begin(); i != s.end(); i++)        cout<<*i;
    cout<<endl;
}
```

Update: Assume that x.length() is always greater than or equal to y.length() in the input itself.

Comment: Have you tried running in a debugger?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg No, but I have used several print statements in the original source code in my system. Still no clue!

Comment: Please try to run it in a debugger. It will stop exactly where the crash happens, and then let you show and walk up the function call stack to your code (if it's not there already) where you can examine values of variables. It's not certain that the problem is actually in the code you show.

Comment: Where's your return statement?

Comment: @Dukeling, Let's say I just want to print the sum in the function and I am storing the value it returns in a string variable from where I am calling this function.

Comment: Undefined behavior is the leading cause of pregnancy.

Comment: Just a note : You should `reserve` memory space for your vector `s`.

Comment: @GabrielL. Sir what do you mean by reserve? It is a vector, and we can push_back() any number of elements we want, right?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/reserve/

Comment: @GabrielL. so what do you think should be an ideal length of a series of chars here to stay safe and not needing about any reserve or resize?

Comment: Since it's an addition, your upper bound for the final number of digits is `max(YLen, XLen) + 1` which is what you want to reserve.

Comment: Yes Sir, that I understand. I was asking in general, how can we be sure that the vector is going to hold, say, this much characters without the need of reserving space for it? For example, here I was testing only with maximum say 20 digits. So what numerical value is the limit beyond which we should worry about reserving?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9866997/how-to-know-the-right-max-size-of-vector-max-size-but-no

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function returns `string`.

You need to return a string, or change that to `void`.

```
void sum(string x, string y) {
```

[Not returning in a value-returning function is undefined behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4290993/1711796) and is probably the cause of your segmentation fault.

Comment: Yes, that is it! Changing it to void and g++ was happy with that. Reason behind this? I mean, more technical reason for the segfault?

Comment: [It's undefined behaviour](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4290993/1711796). A segmentation fault commonly happens here - it's "generally an attempt to access memory that the CPU cannot physically address" (Wikipedia), which sort of makes sense, as the function may be trying to return something it doesn't have access to.

Answer (score 1):

This loop statement

```
for(int i = xLen - 1, j = yLen - 1; i >= 0, j >= 0; i--, j--) {
```

is already wrong.

The second expression in the loop

```
i >= 0, j >= 0
```

is an expression of the comma operator. It does not take into account that i can be less than 0. The value of the expression is the value of the condition j >= 0. So if xLen is less than yLen then you will get that i will be equal to some negative number.

You should rewrite this loop. I think you meant expresssion

```
i >= 0 && j >= 0
```

Comment: Changing it to && still gives a segfault.

Comment: The code is invalid. I showed only one wrong code. The code should be rewritten in whole.